# How to combine two FOR XML AUTO into 1 XML?

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, sql-server-2012, xquery

We are using SQL Server 2012.

- Table `myTbl` has a one to many relationship to table `myAllocation`
- Table `ABC_myTbl` has a one to many relationship to table `ABC_myAllocation`

The below query combined 2 FOR XML AUTO into 1 XML, but the problem is ID, SystemSource, Manager are included in element TradeTicket instead of on their own, and accountManager, unitPrice are included in element allocationRow instead of on their own.

Thank you

```
        SELECT '<?xml version="1.0"?>'+
    (SELECT 
            (   SELECT trTicket.[id],trTicket.[manager],'PFM' as SystemSource
                    ,allocationRow.accountNumber,allocationRow.unitPrice
                FROM myTbl AS trTicket 
                LEFT JOIN myAllocation AS allocationRow ON allocationRow.trade_ticket_id=trTicket.id
                    WHERE trTicket.ID = 8779631
                    ORDER BY trTicket.id,allocationRow.AccountNumber
                FOR XML AUTO, type)
            ,
            (
                SELECT trTicket.[id],trTicket.[manager],'CRD' as SystemSource
                    ,allocationRow.accountNumber,allocationRow.unitPrice
                FROM ABC_myTbl AS trTicket 
                LEFT JOIN ABC_myAllocation AS allocationRow ON allocationRow.trade_ticket_id=trTicket.id
                    WHERE trTicket.ID = 8
                    ORDER BY trTicket.id,allocationRow.AccountNumber
                FOR XML AUTO, type)
    FOR XML PATH('trTickets'), ELEMENTS) AS XMLResult
```

This is the current result:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<trTickets>
<trTicket id="8779631" SystemSource="PFM" manager="MCM">
<allocationRow accountNumber="292 " unit_Price="300"/>
</trTicket>
<trTicket id="8" SystemSource="CRD" manager="DOYLE">
<allocationRow unitPrice="100" accountNumber="F11 "/>
<allocationRow unitPrice="200" accountNumber="F22 "/>
</trTicket>
</trTickets>
```

This is the desired result that I am looking for:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <trTickets>
    <trTicket>
    <id>8</id>
    <manager>DOYLE</manager>
    <SystemSource>CRD</SystemSource>
    <allocationRow>
    <accountNumber>F11</accountNumber>
    <unitPrice>100</unitPrice>
    </allocationRow>
    <allocationRow>
    <accountNumber>F22</accountNumber>
    <unitPrice>200</unitPrice>
    </allocationRow>
    </trTicket>
    <trTicket>
    <id>8779631</id>
    <manager>MCM</manager> 
    <SystemSource>PFM</SystemSource>
    <allocationRow>
    <accountNumber>292</accountNumber>
    <unitPrice>300</unitPrice>
    </allocationRow>
    </trTicket>
    </trTickets>
```

Data sample:

Table `ABC_myTbl`:

```
ID  Manager
-----------
8   DOYLE
```

Table `ABC_myAllocation`:

```
accountNumber   unitPrice
-------------------------
F11             100
F22             200
```

Table `myTbl`:

```
ID      Manager
--------------- 
8779631 MCM
```

Table `myAllocation`:

```
accountNumber   unitPrice
--------------------------
292             300
```

DDL for the tables and their data:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.ABC_myTbl 
(
    ID INT  NOT NULL,
    MANAGER VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE dbo.myTbl 
(
    ID INT  NOT NULL,
    MANAGER VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL
)   

CREATE TABLE dbo.ABC_myAllocation
(
    accountNumber VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    unitprice     NUMERIC(10, 3) NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE dbo.myAllocation
(
    accountNumber VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    unitprice     NUMERIC(10, 3)  NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO dbo.ABC_myTbl VALUES (8,'DOYLE')

INSERT INTO dbo.ABC_myAllocation VALUES ('F11',100)
INSERT INTO dbo.ABC_myAllocation VALUES ('F22',200)

INSERT INTO dbo.myTbl VALUES (8779631,'MCM')

INSERT INTO dbo.myAllocation  VALUES  ('292',300)
```

Comment: It would be great if you could provide a minimal reproducible sample:
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT, T-SQL statements.
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic.
(3) Desired output based on the sample data from #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;)

Comment: Hi, I have added the DDL for the tables and their data in my original post. My desired XML output is listed at the end of the post. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't wait for your DDL and sample data population. So I created a conceptual sample for you. Please pay attention that the tables have implied relationships and they are used in the `WHERE` clauses.

> SQL

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl1 TABLE (ID INT PRIMARY KEY, Manager VARCHAR(20));
INSERT INTO @tbl1 (ID, Manager) VALUES
(8, 'DOYLE'),
(9, 'XYZ');

DECLARE @tbl1Child TABLE (accountNumber CHAR(3) PRIMARY KEY, ParentID INT, unitPrice DECIMAL(10,2));
INSERT INTO @tbl1Child (accountNumber, ParentID, unitPrice) VALUES
('F11', 8, 100)
,('F22', 8, 200)
,('F70', 9, 770);

DECLARE @tbl2 TABLE (ID INT PRIMARY KEY, Manager VARCHAR(20));
INSERT INTO @tbl2 (ID, Manager) VALUES
(8779631, 'MCM')
,(8779555, 'TTT');

DECLARE @tbl2Child TABLE (accountNumber CHAR(3) PRIMARY KEY, ParentID INT, unitPrice DECIMAL(10,2));
INSERT INTO @tbl2Child (accountNumber, ParentID, unitPrice) VALUES
('292', 8779631, 300)
,('255', 8779555, 500);
-- DDL and sample data population, end

SELECT TOP(1) NULL
, (
    SELECT *
        , (
            SELECT * FROM @tbl1Child AS c
            WHERE p.ID = c.ParentID
            FOR XML PATH('allocation_row'), TYPE
        ) 
    FROM @tbl1 AS p
    FOR XML PATH('tradeTicket'), TYPE
)
, (
    SELECT *
        , (
            SELECT * FROM @tbl2Child AS c
            WHERE p.ID = c.ParentID
            FOR XML PATH('allocation_row'), TYPE
    ) 
    FROM @tbl2 AS p
    FOR XML PATH('tradeTicket'), TYPE
)
FROM @tbl1
FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE, ROOT('tradeTickets');
```

> Output

```
<tradeTickets>
  <tradeTicket>
    <ID>8</ID>
    <Manager>DOYLE</Manager>
    <allocation_row>
      <accountNumber>F11</accountNumber>
      <ParentID>8</ParentID>
      <unitPrice>100.00</unitPrice>
    </allocation_row>
    <allocation_row>
      <accountNumber>F22</accountNumber>
      <ParentID>8</ParentID>
      <unitPrice>200.00</unitPrice>
    </allocation_row>
  </tradeTicket>
  <tradeTicket>
    <ID>9</ID>
    <Manager>XYZ</Manager>
    <allocation_row>
      <accountNumber>F70</accountNumber>
      <ParentID>9</ParentID>
      <unitPrice>770.00</unitPrice>
    </allocation_row>
  </tradeTicket>
  <tradeTicket>
    <ID>8779555</ID>
    <Manager>TTT</Manager>
    <allocation_row>
      <accountNumber>255</accountNumber>
      <ParentID>8779555</ParentID>
      <unitPrice>500.00</unitPrice>
    </allocation_row>
  </tradeTicket>
  <tradeTicket>
    <ID>8779631</ID>
    <Manager>MCM</Manager>
    <allocation_row>
      <accountNumber>292</accountNumber>
      <ParentID>8779631</ParentID>
      <unitPrice>300.00</unitPrice>
    </allocation_row>
  </tradeTicket>
</tradeTickets>
```

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, our tables don't have the dependency ParentID that's on your table. With my tables, I had created something that is similar to my expected result. The only problem is ID, SystemSource, Manager, accountNumber, unitPrice are not their own element. I have updated my original post with this.

Comment: in your OP you mentioned twice that there are one-to-many relationships between tables. How is it implemented on the DB level?

Comment: For each myTbl id there could be 0 to many trade_ticket_id in myAllocation table. For each ABC_myTbl id there could be 0 to many trade_ticket_id in ABC_myAllocation table.    Thus, the LEFT JOIN here: ....FROM myTbl AS trTicket LEFT JOIN myAllocation AS allocationRow ON allocationRow.trade_ticket_id=trTicket.id

Comment: Ok. So try to use the approach I showed, and use `WHERE` clauses instead of your `LEFT OUTER JOIN` joins.

Comment: Hi, @"Yitzhak Khabinsky" In your example, if there are more than 1 IDS in tbl1 or tbl2, for example: INSERT INTO tbl1 (ID, Manager) VALUES (9, 'XYZ'), the XML puts all IDs under the same <t>. I need each IDs to be in each own <t>. How can I do that ? I posted this question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61082358/how-to-combine-two-for-xml-path-into-1-xml

Comment: I updated the solution based on the changed requirements.

Comment: Thank you so much !! You rock !

Comment: And, I deleted the other post. Thank you !